# apply mask from WHERE to a higher dimension array

Tags: fortran, where-clause

I want to apply the results from a WHERE construct to other arrays that have a higher dimension, so that in the following the "-" marks the indices from WHERE.  I was wondering if FINDLOC could help, but seems it can not use a logical expression.  Is there some kind of ARGWHERE intrinsic I am unaware of to return the indices and apply them ?

```
PROGRAM test
REAL :: a(3,20,20),b(20,20),c(20,20)
CALL random_number(c)
a=1
b=1
WHERE (c<0.5) 
  c=0
  b=0 ! this is fine
  a(:,-,-)=0 ! how to do this???
ENDWHERE
END PROGRAM test
```

Comment: Or use `spread` to uprank the mask and apply it, in another `where` construct, to `a`.

Comment: thanks , didn't know about spread, I'll try it out

Comment: or, how about using a do-loop like do i = 1, 3 ; where (mask) a(i, :,:) = 0; enddo? (where mask <-> c < 1.0e-6, or mask = c < 0.5 etc)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - apologies for being uninformed, but how do you actually get the mask of indices back, would that need the pack statement?

Comment: I have to say I think I would just use nested do loops for the whole lot - all the discussion be seems to abut forcing something into a model that doesn't quite fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `b` array, which has the same size as `c`, perhaps using `MERGE` would be more elegant:

```
b = MERGE(1,0,c>=0.5)
```

The same could be done with `a`, in a less elegant but still compact way:

```
FORALL(i=1:20,j=1:20) a(:,i,j) = merge(1,0,c(i,j)>=0.5)
```

Both these commands will provide an assigment to ALL elements in your arrays. If you want the filtering operation only, regardless of the initial values in the array, then perhaps they could be reduced to a `WHERE` construct:

```
FORALL(i=1:20,j=1:20,c(i,j)<0.5) a(:,i,j) = 0.0
WHERE (c<0.5) 
   b=0.0
   c=0.0
END WHERE
```

*** edit ***
As per @HighPerformanceMark's suggestion, the latter example could be packed as

```
FORALL (i=1:20,j=1:20,c(i,j)<0.5)
   a(:,i,j) = 0.0
   b  (i,j) = 0.0
   c  (i,j) = 0.0
END FORALL
```

Comment: Many thanks for the sugestion, but it is a pity that the test on c needs to be run twice - this solution is similar to my current approach which was a separate nested do loop over i and j, but the double check is not very efficient.

Comment: The test on `c` doesn't *need* to be run twice, the *forall statement* could be extended to a *forall construct* and enclose the assignments.

Comment: These days `do concurrent` is somewhat preferred to `forall` which is rather deprecated (in practice rather than in the standard) for (potentially) creating temporary array copies in some cases where they are not strictly required.